# Will a curve having infinite length, contained into a set of $\mathbb R^2$ always intersect itself?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I have a question(for which I am sure there is already an answer) however not being able to spot the answer online I decided to ask my question in this forum. Suppose that we have a set $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$ as shown in the picture:[image]. My question is: Can there exist a curve of infinite length contained in $S$ so that the curve does not intersect itself? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Yes. For example the Koch snowflake has infinite length but does not  self intersect.

Comment: A simpler example: the graphics of $\sin(1/x)$ for $x$ in a $(0,1/\pi]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "$S$ as shown in the picture" means that its interior, $S^\circ$, is nonempty, here's a way to construct a smooth curve of infinite length contained in $S$.

**Hint** Since $S^\circ$ is nonempty, $S$ contains some open ball $B$, say, of radius $a > 0$. Then pick a function $f(\theta)$

- that is positive and strictly increasing
- that is bounded above by the radius $a$, and
- whose domain contains an interval of the form $(\theta_0, \infty)$.

For concreteness, we could take $f(\theta) = a \tanh \theta$, $\theta \in (0, \infty)$. Then, consider the curve defined in polar coordinates centered at the center of the ball by $r = f(\theta)$.

Comment: Assuming that "S as shown in the picture" means nonempty and open - Does it? To me it looks closed (otherwise one would cross out the boundary, wouldn't one?).

Comment: @Filippo I'm not sure exactly what hypotheses OP has in mind. But one could loosen the assumption to $S$ having nonempty interior, in which case the argument proceeds just as before, after replacing $S$ by $S^\circ$ in the first line of the hint.

Comment: If $S$ is simply connected (roughly speaking, has no holes) and not the whole plane, one can even arrange for a curve of infinite length such that each point in $\partial S$ is a limit point of the curve.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a spiral that starts at the center of a ball and slowly converges towards the boundary of that ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you see how?
Notice that this shows that any open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains such a curve.